# Nginx Install doesn't create /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I'm installing Nginx using Passenger on an ubuntu server. I install Nginx using `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` but when I try to create a Nginx script using `nano /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx` the directory rc.d does not exist. Any idea why?

I have the directories rc0.d through rc6.d but none of them have the init.d file in them. I'm following the [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-ruby-on-rails-application-deployments-using-capistrano)

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in detail in the Passenger documentation here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_rvm/#note_about_nginx

The solution is to [install Nginx from the Phusion Passenger APT repository](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/apt_repo.html), or to [create an Nginx init script yourself](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/nginx_init_script.html).

Comment: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx_init_script.html returns with **404** erorr

Comment: That page has been moved to https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/nginx_init_script.html a few days ago.